# Create a BITMAPINFO from a JPG/PNG file in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, image, bitmap

I have a function in an API I am using that request a BITMAPINFO pointer. I am suppose to give this function an image. My images are JPG/PNGs. Suppose I transform them to BMP files, I have still no clue on how to set up this struct. Is there a windows API that I can use for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GDI+ for this.
Read BMP/JPG/PNG/GIF using [Gdiplus::Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)::FromFile to load and [Gdiplus::Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)::GetHBITMAP to access HBITMAP and then BITMAPINFO

Comment: That would be using **GDI+**, not GDI.

Comment: The link between `HBITMAP` and `BITMAPINFO` isn't obvious.  The [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904.aspx) function will fill in a `DIBSECTION` structure based on an `HBITMAP`, and `DIBSECTION` uses the same `BITMAPINFOHEADER` substructure as `BITMAPINFO`.

Comment: I didn't understand how I access `BITMAPINFO` from `HBITMAP`. Code example will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google turns up this MSDN article: [Sizing a JPEG or PNG Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which show one way of filling a BITMAPINFO for a JPEG file (would work for PNG).

Use the links on the left of that page to get more information about the bitmap API.

Comment: Be warned that this format of `BITMAPINFO` might not work with functions other than `StretchDIBits`.

Answer (score 0):

PNGs have, potentially, AlphaChannel/transparency information -- which gets lost when converting to a bitmap.  What does your function that requires BITMAPINFO actually do ?

If your approach is to transform the files to bitmaps; don't do that at runtime.
Convert the files using a paint program to bmp.

As previously mentioned, you can use GDI+ to make use of several different native formats;
but doing so will likely require converting your existing GDI calls to GDI+.